# Bitmap Font upside down when using AssetManager

Tags: java, fonts, bitmap, libgdx

Today I started using the `AssetManager` from `libGDX` to load my assets. Before that I already loaded everything in a separate class, but I didn't use the `AssetManager`.
How I currently load the Bitmap Font:

```
manager.load("font/good_neighbors_unity.fnt", BitmapFont.class);
[...]
bFont = manager.get("font/good_neighbors_unity.fnt", BitmapFont.class);
```

My problem is that the bitmap font I use is upside down when I load it with the Asset Manager. This is due to the fact that in my orthographic camera, *y* is pointing down. In the Bitmap Font constructor there is a boolean to flip the font and avoid this problem. But there seems to be no such option when I load it with the `AssetManager`. There is probably a relatively easy solution to this, but I can't find any method that allows me to flip the font afterwards. Is there an option that allows me flip the bitmap font while using the `AssetManager`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify flip to the asset manager using a parameter object.

```
BitmapFontLoader.BitmapFontParameter bitmapFontParameter = new BitmapFontParameter();
bitmapFontParameter.flip = true;
manager.load("font/good_neighbors_unity.fnt", BitmapFont.class, bitmapFontParameter);
```

A double brace in an anonymous class might let you do this as a one-liner:

```
manager.load("font/good_neighbors_unity.fnt", BitmapFont.class, new BitmapFontLoader.BitmapFontParameter(){{flip = true;}});
```

Comment: Thanks allot. That's what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately you cannot **flip** the font after created but you can set negative scale to achieve an effect of flipping.

Just use:

```
    label.setFontScale(-1);
```

You can also try with **label.setFontScaleX** and **label.setFontScaleY**